# IP6tables does not apply ACCEPT rules

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

My server is an IPv6 only server, I'm trying to write firewall rules using ip6tables and it looks something like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             /* Allow loopback interface packets */
2    ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
4    ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
5    ACCEPT     tcp      anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ssh traffic */
6    DROP       all      anywhere             anywhere             /* Drop the remaining packets */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

As expected without the last rule I'm able to access my webserver and ssh into it, but adding the last rule blocks everything even with 3,4,5 rule in place. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you share `ip6tables-save` output instead?

Comment: Even `ip6tables-save -c` to have `-c` provide hit counters too.